# How to find third standard deviation of a half-norm shaped distribution in python or R?

Tags: python, r, scipy, normal-distribution, scipy.stats

I have a data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df = pd.DataFrame([100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 5, 1, 0.9, 0.07, 0.001, 0.00001], columns=['Frequency'])
```

I assume this data follows a half norm distribution.

```
df.sort_values(by='Frequency').plot.bar(y='Frequency')
plt.savefig('test_dist.png')
```

This visualization results in:

[image]

How can I first fit a half-norm (half bell shape) distribution on this data and then return the third standard deviation? I could find the `scipy.stats.halfnorm` but don't know how  to use it. I'm open to other languages such as R if you know a solution with R.

Comment: What is a “third standard deviation “?

Comment: Here is a question about it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699342/calculate-the-3rd-standard-deviation-for-an-array

Comment: I think it's ```df['Frequency'].mean() - 3 * df['Frequency'].std()``` for a normal distribution (not a half normal)

Comment: Are you trying to get the third central moment?

Comment: I'm not sure what a "central moment" is. Is it like a mean?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I first fit a half-norm (half bell shape) distribution on this data

SciPy has functions for fitting distributions to raw samples; it doesn't accept histograms or weighted samples. Assuming that the observed values are the integers 0-15 (as in your figure) and that some approximation is OK, we can multiply each observed value by the nearest integer frequency.

```py
import numpy as np
freqs = [100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 5, 1, 0.9, 0.07, 0.001, 0.00001]
freqs = np.asarray(freqs).round().astype(int)  # approximation: round to integers
# freqs = (np.asarray(freqs)*1000).astype(int)  # less approximation, slow
# freqs = (np.asarray(freqs)*100000).astype(int) # no approximation, very slow
vals = np.arange(len(freqs))
sample = np.repeat(vals, freqs)
```

Now `sample` is an array with 100 0s, 90 1s, ..., 0 14s, and 0 15s.

To fit a halfnorm distribution:

```py
from scipy import stats
# assume `loc` is fixed at 0
loc, scale = stats.halfnorm(sample, floc=0)
```

I'm going to interpret "third standard deviation" as three times the standard deviation of the corresponding (full) normal distribution. The `scale` parameter is the standard deviation of the corresponding normal distribution, so you wanted three times that:

```py
3 * scale  # 12.069124831118353
```

Just to make sure we're on the same page, here's what this looks like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dist = stats.halfnorm(loc, scale)
pdf = dist.pdf(vals)
plt.plot(vals, pdf, label='fitted half-normal')
plt.hist(sample, bins=vals, density=True, label='histogram')
plt.xlabel('value')
plt.ylabel('frequency density')
plt.title('Histogram of Data and fitted Half-Normal PDF')
plt.legend()
```

The survival function (probability mass left in the right tail) at `3 * scale` is:

```py
dist.sf(3 * scale)  # 0.0026997960632601866
```

which is twice as much as you'd have at 3σ if this were a full normal distribution.